# Aoson M19 -- Need Device Drivers

Tags: usb-drivers

Myself and a few others have an extra Aoson M19 android tablet on hand, but can't seem to find any USB device drivers for it. I assume this is because it isn't an overly popular tablet.

Does anyone know where some drivers could be found? Perhaps someone wrote their own?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Found this..

> After a few days working with this beautiful tablet i must say it's better than i expected. Great screen, fast enough (i never tested games).
>   Now i'm intersting to conect the tablet with a usb cable to my windows 7 desktop.
>   Please tell me where i can find drivers so i can synchronize it with the program i use (my phone explorer).
>   With the drivers i found i can only see and work with the files on the memory of my tablet.
>   Thank you in advance.
>
> ANSWER:
>   thank you for taking the time to post a review, please email us at techhelp@merimobiles.com we will send you the windows drivers, thank you

So it looks like they're not publicly available, but try emailing this company and you might get them as well!

Comment: no problem! let us know if they're able to help you or not.

Comment: I will certainly post back on my experience with Aoson support.

Comment: Aoson never replied to my email & I have moved onto using other tablets for development. Good luck to any other Aoson users.

Comment: Sorry it did not work out for you :/ but good luck with your new adventures!