# Aoson M19 -- Device Drivers

Tags: usb-drivers

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Aoson M19 — Need Device Drivers](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/23449/aoson-m19-need-device-drivers)

Myself and a few others have an extra Aoson M19 android tablet on hand, but can't seem to find any USB device drivers for it. I assume this is because it isn't an overly popular tablet.

Does anyone know where some drivers could be found? Perhaps someone wrote their own?

I have already tried the Google drivers and the drivers providers listed on developer.android.com- please don't point me there.

Thanks.

Comment: Wow. That's not great for a company not to have publicly available drivers -- I guess it's one of those off-brand chinese tablets though, isn't it? Good luck, hope you can find them!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For others who might encounter this problem, [HERE](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/23449/aoson-m19-need-device-drivers/23450#23450) is where I re-asked this question.

The solution is that you need to email the company at this address: techhelp@merimobiles.com

And you will be helped, supposedly. I will post back on whether this works for me.

UPDATE:
No one ever responded to my email... Good luck other Aoson users.